# Excel external reference - how do they update?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble understanding the external formula reference.

Let's say I have two worksheets - worksheet Display.xlsm, and worksheet Backend.xlsm.

Backend has a cell A1 and inside it has `=TODAY()`

Display on the other hand, in cell A1 has `'[Backend.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$1`

Scenario:

1. Save Backend.xlsm today, never open it again
2. Keep Display.xlsm opened 24/7
3. Will the date in Display A1 keep updating as the day pass by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

**Display.xlsm** will update, however value will not change. When you close **Backend.xlsm**, it is also stop checking function and saves the last value (for Today() it saved me `41745`). This file will not autoupdate in the background if not opened - that would be awful action and our machines could die from non-stop checking :)

When you open **Backend.xlsm** again it will check function and update but it will not as it is closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a big shame as it means that certain mechanisms will have to be duplicated across several worksheets instead of having a centralised source of data.

Comment: Maybe describe your idea of mechanism you are talking about. There may be another solution.

Comment: Calculations of days between todays date and set date. Around 100 of set dates, with number of days between today and the dates updating every day.

Comment: Hm... if you use `Workbook_Open` event with **Display.xlsm** and enter code to open **Display.xlsm** as hidden you can refer as long as you like. However I suppose dates are inserted not only be you?

Comment: You can unnoticeably open an excel file? I'm not aware of that.

Comment: Unnotiveably or almost unnoticeably. Enter code in `Workbook_open` event of **Display.xlsm** to open **Backend.xlsm** and then to hide it. You barely can see something happend. What is important you need to unhide it at some point and close it.

Comment: In that case no, but you can create a button "Load data", which will open this document and hide it. You can also create another button to "Unload data" or "Refresh data". So workbook will open, update `Today()` and so will **Display.xlsm** have current data. After that "update" it will automatically close.